# How would I run gedit on a text file on a remote server?

Tags: ssh, gedit

I've seen answers to this talking about how to run gedit on the remote server. But what I'm looking for is a way to run gedit locally, where the server only provides the data. Is there a way to do this? I'm running ubuntu 16.04

I already tried `sftp`, and that didn't work. I know I could use `scp` and then use gedit locally, but I'm trying to avoid the overhead of putting the right file back into the right spot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `sshfs` to mount a directory on the server on a local directory over SSH.

1. If you don't already have `sshfs` installed then install it:

   ```
    sudo apt-get install sshfs
   ```

   This will also install any dependencies needed.
2. Mount a remote directory on a local directory:

   ```
    sshfs user@host:/path/to/remote/dir /path/to/local/dir
   ```

   You must have write access to the local directory. If the remote path does not begin with a slash it is taken to be relative to the remote user's home directory.
3. You can now access the files in the remote directory as if they were in the local directory. The access to the files in the remote directory will be done with the remote user account with which you have connected. For example, you can run `gedit` to edit a file:

   ```
   gedit /path/to/local/dir/file </dev/null &>/dev/null &
   ```

   The actual file is of course on the remote server at `/path/to/remote/dir/file`.
4. When you are done unmount the remote folder:

   ```
   fusermount -u /path/to/local/dir
   ```

You don't have to install anything on the remote computer; the access to files is made over the regular SSH protocol. After installing `sshfs` you can use `man sshfs` for detailed information.

Answer (score 5):

## Use `Nautilus` to connect to the remote server

Try using sftp from `nautilus`. Nautilus shows up as "Files" in the launchbar in Ubuntu. To use sftp:

1. Open nautilus in your **local** computer.
2. Click on **Connect to Servers** in the left panel
3. Type something like

   sftp://your.url.goes.here./home/userid

or

```
sftp://your.IP_address.goes.here./home/userid
```

4. Click **Connect** button

If all goes well you will be prompted for password and you will see the files in the remote server's folder `/home/userid`.

5. Bookmark this server information for future easy use.
6. Use `gedit` by clicking on text the files on the remote server.
7. When you are done editing and browsing the files in the remote server, you can disconnect from the server by clicking on the **eject icon** next to the server connection in the left panel of **Nautilus**.

Thanks to [ianorlin](https://askubuntu.com/users/189045/ianorlin) `sftp` works from many other file managers, such as pcmanfm, thunar, caja, and nemo. The location and exact method varies.

I hope this helps

Comment: I can't find "Connect to Servers". Does it exist on ubuntu?

Comment: Found it. Sorry, I hadn't updated my browser since you edited the comment when I responded.

Comment: This actually works with a lot more file managers than just natilus. both the gtk and Qt versions of pcmanfm, thunar, caja, and nemo all depend on that which s most of the gtk desktop environments and LXQt. Of course these have slighty different places in the ui to find each of theese.

Comment: @ianorlin thanks! I have added a note based on your comments.